# GetAdapterIndex() return wrong index

Tags: winapi, network-programming

I want to get adapter index by its name, after couple days of searching I found [GetAdapterIndex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")

#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x)) 
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))

int main()
{
    DWORD res;
    DWORD rs;
    ULONG IfIndex;
    LPWSTR AdapterName;
    int i = 0;
    res = GetAdapterIndex(L"AMD PCNET Family PCI Ethernet Adapter - Packet Scheduler Miniport", &IfIndex);
    if(res == NO_ERROR)
        printf("Adapter Index: %ld\n", IfIndex);

    res = GetNumberOfInterfaces(&rs);
    if(res == NO_ERROR)
        printf("Number of Adapters: %ld\n", rs);
return 0;
}
```

**First:** it doesn't return an index for the specific adapter name I chose.
**Second:** It returns that I have two adapters, even I have just only one.

Comment: @arx Can you test the code in your OS, I am using Win XP SP3 with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Yes, my Windows 7 laptop has 33 network adapters!  Only two are physical.  You can print their names and descriptions using `GetIfEntry` (indices start at 1).  All the names are of the form `\DEVICE\TCPIP_{846EE342-7039-11DE-9D20-806E6F6E6963}` which explains why you aren't finding your adapter using the nice name.

Comment: @arx That is right, I just figured that. Please make your comment as answer so I can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the names and descriptions of network interfaces using `GetIfEntry`, with indices ranging from 1 to the value returned by `GetNumberOfInterfaces`.  All the names are of the form `\DEVICE\TCPIP_{846EE342-7039-11DE-9D20-806E6F6E6963}` which explains why you aren't finding your interface using the nice name.